# SMS not saving in inbox

Tags: android, sms, message

I have the following code:

it doesn't save to my inbox

```
try{
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        String message = bundle.getString("message");
        String pnumber = bundle.getString("number");
        String time = bundle.getString("timestamp");
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(pnumber, null, message, null, null);
        Toast.makeText(context,"Message Sent to " + pnumber,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ContentValues my_values = new ContentValues();
        my_values.put("body", message);
        my_values.put("address", pnumber);          
        context.getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), my_values);
    }
    catch(Exception e){

        Toast.makeText(context, "Error but Received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Please help me how to save this sent sms

Comment: Have you added '<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />'
permission in your manifest file?

Comment: U added now ?? Is it still not working?

Answer (score 0):

If you want save in INBOX, you need set Uri: `content://sms/inbox`. In your example - `"content://sms/sent"`